# Highlight dates on datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to highlight multiple dates in a datepicker. The highlighted dates needs to be captured as inputs when I click on them. When I do this with bootstrap datepicker multiple option I get lots of dates on the input field. when I click the date the color of the date disappear as well. 
Any plugin to get this done? or any customization to the bootstrap datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a directive based on Bootstrap datepicker. Fortunately, the AngularUI Team have already created one that allows you to do this: [Datepicker directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)